# Custom Slider Taking Too Much Space

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uislider

I used a code from [here](https://priva28.medium.com/making-a-custom-slider-in-swiftui-db440cd6d88c) to create my own variation of a custom slider. However, the slider has too much extra space at the bottom, and I would like to remove that. Is there any way to do so?
Here is the code of the slider:

```
struct CustomSlider: View {
    
    @Binding var value: CGFloat
    
    @State var lastOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var range: ClosedRange<CGFloat>
    var leadingOffset: CGFloat = 5
    var trailingOffset: CGFloat = 5
    
    var knobSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)
    
    let trackGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.pink, .yellow]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color(hue: 0.172, saturation: 0.275, brightness: 1.0))
                    .frame(height: 30)
                
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color(hue: 0.55, saturation: 0.326, brightness: 1.0))
                    .frame(width: self.$value.wrappedValue.map(from: self.range, to: self.leadingOffset...(geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset))+30, height: 30)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                        .frame(width: self.knobSize.width, height: self.knobSize.height)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .offset(x: self.$value.wrappedValue.map(from: self.range, to: self.leadingOffset...(geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset)))
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    
                                    if abs(value.translation.width) < 0.1 {
                                        self.lastOffset = self.$value.wrappedValue.map(from: self.range, to: self.leadingOffset...(geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset))
                                    }
                                    
                                    let sliderPos = max(0 + self.leadingOffset, min(self.lastOffset + value.translation.width, geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset))
                                    let sliderVal = sliderPos.map(from: self.leadingOffset...(geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset), to: self.range)
                                    
                                    self.value = sliderVal
                                }
                            
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have noticed that when I select the empty space, the code cased in geometry reader is automatically selected. (I couldn't embed the image in this post, so here's the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIcMy.jpg))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `GeometryReader`, it automatically takes up all available space. If you'd like to constrain it, use a `frame(height: )` modifier to give it a certain height.

```
struct CustomSlider: View {
    
    //all of the properties

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
          // slider code
        }.frame(height: 60) //<-- Here
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't know that GeometryReader takes up all the available much space. Thank you so much!